# Query to return string prior to a specific character

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have a column in a table and it has some values, I need a SQL query to return the string prior to a specific character

For example if the column holds the following values

```
Col1
------------------
ABC_method ~~ AMQ
BCCCC_TEST ~~ POQ
AO ~~ OOO
```

The output should be

```
ABC_method
BCCCC_TEST
AO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substr and Instr:

```
select case
         when Col1 like '%~%' then substr(Col1, 1, instr(Col1, '~') -1)
         else Col1
       end as Col1Short
from MyTable
```

Comment: Hey @JohnHC is doesn't give the desired output it just shows blank fields

Comment: the previous one worked there was a problem with the DB refresh, thanks

Answer (score 1):

With a regexp, you could use:

```
select regexp_substr(Col1, '[^~]*')
from test
```

But you don't need regexp for this; you could even use:

```
select case
        when instr(Col1, '~') > 0 then substr(Col1, 1, instr(Col1, '~')-1)
        else Col1
       end
from test
```

The regexp approach is more compact, but slower.

If you are sure that every string has at least one occurrence of the separator character (`~` in your example), you can avoid the `case`:

```
select substr(Col1, 1, instr(Col1, '~')-1)       
from test
```

Answer (score 0):

This includes finding a starting point if it is not at position one.  You may need to modify the pluses and minuses to fit.

```
select substr(Col1, startnum, endnum - startnum) as myoutput
from
(select instr(Col1, 'something')+ 1 startnum,
       instr(Col1, '~~') -1  as endnum,
       Col1
from tablenamehere) getnums;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN col1 like 'AMQ' THEN
          'ABC_method'
         WHEN col1 like 'POQ' THEN
          'BCCCC_TEST'
         ELSE
          'AO'
       END as type
FROM table t
```